# Using threads or tasks with MVC3 AJAX calls

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC3 project with .NET 4.5 (we can't upgrade to MVC4 for various reasons). I have a need to run three database queries, each of which takes a couple seconds, to populate three sets of data in an AJAX request.

My initial thought was to just make 3 separate AJAX calls, but I ran into issues with maximum concurrent AJAX requests - we have a lot of other AJAX calls going on at the same time, so these 3 were blocked on the client while waiting for all the calls to clear.

So I'm trying to put it in a single AJAX call, but I still want to execute the three queries simultaneously.

Since it's MVC3, I apparently can't do the simple `async Task<JsonResult>` with `await Task.WhenAll(tasks)` on three tasks.

I haven't done a lot of multi-threading other than simple "fire-and-forget" stuff, so I want to make sure I'm doing this right.

The following simple way works properly, but I'm pretty sure it's not the right way - I've read a lot of people talking about how ASP.NET is picky about thread handling, especially as you start to use a lot of threads.

```
var threads = new List<Thread>();
threads.Add(new Thread(() => x1 = Method1()));
threads.Add(new Thread(() => x2 = Method2()));
threads.Add(new Thread(() => x3 = Method3()));
threads.ForEach(t => t.Start());
threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
// x1, x2, and x3 are now populated
```

What do I need to change in order to properly use the ThreadPool or whatever other threading techniques I should be considering, and make sure I close things properly? The site generally has only a few dozen concurrent users, and this call would be made whenever they load up a page - so it's not a huge number of threads.

I'll also add exception handling to make sure nothing blows up.

Comment: I certainly do not recommend multithreading for asynchronous work. Use `AsyncManager`/`AsyncController` instead. If you absolutely insist on threading, at least use `Parallel` instead of `Thread`.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks - I originally just wanted to use normal async Tasks all the way through but got shut down when I found that MVC3 apparently can't do async actions - I thought that meant TPL didn't work at all, but that doesn't seem to be the case. I did get things working fine by creating tasks with `Task.Factory` - would you agree that this would be a good approach? Or would it really be worth putting together an `AsyncController`?

Comment: No, I would not recommend `Task.Factory.StartNew` (though `Task.Factory.FromAsync` would be fine).

Comment: @StephenCleary I'll give it a try, thank you. I appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What do I need to change in order to properly use the ThreadPool or whatever other threading techniques I should be considering, and make sure I close things properly?

*It depends*.

Your current code [won't reuse a thread from the thread pool and possibly thread-starve the PoolThread causing a 500 (ASP.Net request processing stalled because the CLR thread pool is out of threads)](http://blog.leansentry.com/2013/07/all-about-iis-asp-net-request-queues/).  There is a small performance penalty for bringing up a new thread (which is why the thread pool exists in the first place), but for high through-output high concurrency websites, this is a good choice.

That being said, if your website is servicing a low through-output low concurrent user base, it's over kill in my opinion. It's much easier on the eyes (opinion) to use the [`Task.Factory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.factory.aspx).  This will use thread in the thread pool, but unless you're running the website on a single-core machine, I doubt anyone will notice.

Outside of the threading models, there are much more *architectural* ways to reduce database hits, but your question is so specific, there isn't much I could suggest without knowing more.

Comment: Thanks, `Task.Factory` ended up working well - looks like MVC3 can still handle working with `Task`s, but just not as a return type on an action method. As far as the architectural design, I'm with you 100% - I'd love to get some caching in here, or proper queueing or some other real solution - just don't have the time right now.

Comment: Actually I think [AsyncController was added in MVC 1.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx), but it's a real pain to implement without using `await`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that, but just at a glance so far, I definitely like the Task pattern better than the Begin/Completed and the `AsyncManager.OutstandingOperations`.